# Postgres UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

I have been locked out of cacti after setting guest_user=admin :(
So I am trying to recover my access

```
cacti=# select * from settings;
           name            | value
-------------------------------------------
 auth_method               | 1
 guest_user                | admin
```

When I try to run the query:

```
UPDATE settings SET guest_user = 'No User' WHERE guest_user = 'admin';
```

I get the error:

```
cacti=# UPDATE settings SET guest_user = 'No User' WHERE guest_user = 'admin';
ERROR:  column "guest_user" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE settings SET guest_user = 'No User' WHERE guest_user ...
```

Database is postgres and I am new to it. (its the first time I use it :-) )

Comment: try `UPDATE settings SET value = 'No User' WHERE name = 'guest_user';` because the column names are name and value,

Comment: @fvu: You should post that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
UPDATE settings SET value = 'No User' WHERE name = 'guest_user';
```

because the column names are name and value